# Exact solution of advection PDE with numerical scheme

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, linear-pde, transport-equation

Consider the advection pde $v_t + a v_x = 0$ and let $R = \frac{a \Delta t }{\Delta x}$. Then, the FTFS scheme is given by

$$ u_k^{n+1} = u_k^n - R (u_{k+1}^n - u_k^n ) $$

and $u_k^n = u(k \Delta x, n \Delta t)$. Suppose we take $R=-1$ and assume $a<0$, then we see that our scheme becomes

$$ u_k^{n+1} = u_{k+1}^n $$

now my books says: it is easy to see that this scheme produces exact solution.

Im having hard time trying to see why this is true.

I know that solution of this PDE is constant along characteristiscs $x-a=t$. Maybe this would help, but I still don't see how this may help.

In other, suppose $U(x,t)$ is the exact solution. We are trying to show then that $U-u=0$. If we replace this in our scheme we have

$$ U_k^{n+1} - U_{k+1}^n =0 $$

but even if we use Taylor series, i dont see how we can prove $U-u=0$. Any advice?

Comment: $$u_{k}^{n+1} = u_{k+1}^{n}$$ just says that the solution at position $k+1$ and at time $n$ _is shifted_ to position $k$ at time $n+1$, which is exactly what the 'true' solution should be doing (think about a perfect wave travelling in space with conservation of energy and momentum). I remember having this exact same confusion when I first numerically computed the solution as you have above and the solution had no error between it and the 'true' solution.