# Is it a valid claim that ODEs are easier to solve numerically than PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

My final project in my Partial Differential Equations class involved studying one non-linear PDE in depth. In reading about my equation, I've realized that PDEs of 3 spatial variables can be re-written as an ODE if you assume spherical symmetry (which, for the vast majority of physical applications of this equation, you can).

I'm trying to motivate this change to an ODE, but the resulting ODE is non-linear and not analytically solvable (just like the original PDE). I want to claim that this is still useful because the methods for approximating ODEs (Runge-Kutta, mostly) are "better" than methods for approximating PDEs (finite element/difference/volume methods). However, I'm not familiar with these methods, and think the time learning them would be better spent on other parts of the project.

Is it a "generally accepted" claim that solving an ODE numerically is easier or more accurate than a PDE?

Comment: Whether or not the new approach is better than standard methods is something that must be determined by numerical experiment (or by careful proofs). But the approach sounds interesting regardless, so you could take a more neutral viewpoint and describe your method without firmly claiming it is superior to other methods. Or, you can probably implement a finite difference method easily and compare against that.

Comment: I'd say that it is __not__ true that we can always expect that the transformed PDE can be numerically solved more efficiently. There are various extremely efficient numerical algorithms for specific PDE problems and there's no a priori reason to think that transforming them into  ODEs and solve them with Runge-Kutta is better.

Comment: (continued) By the way, Runge-Kutta is not always the preferred method in solving ODEs. There are also other multi-stage methods or multi-step methods that are more suitable for different tasks, not to mention that practical algorithms would probably have some form of predictor-corrector pair built-in. It seems like your understanding of numerical analysis is a little bit too limited to make such a strong claim about numerically solving ODEs and PDEs in general.

Comment: @Shogun He did say that he is studying a particular *nonlinear* PDE, and we don't know which PDE it is. Many PDEs courses don't discuss nonlinear PDEs at all.

Comment: 'Is it a valid claim that ODEs are easier to solve numerically than PDEs?' I don't think so. [Take this for example.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187079/exact-solution-of-advection-pde-with-numerical-scheme#comment6559290_3187079)

Answer (score 2):

Numerical methods are often based around full derivatives and not partial derivatives. 
Of course "easier" is not a quantifiable term but there are more (accurate) methods of solving ODEs numerically than there are of solving PDEs.
Furthermore more, what will validate your claim is a solid proof or if this is for a thesis than just "enough" examples.